# How do I use e (Eurler's number) and log function correctly in Python?

Tags: python, math, eulers-number

I'm just trying out maths functions in Python as I'm very new to it and I've noticed something when using e. I'm trying to work out log(1+e^2) which I know from using a calculator is 0.9237 but when I type this out in PyCharm, I get 2.1269.

I've tried setting x = (1+e^2) then doing log(x) in case it's working things out in the wrong order. But even if you get 1+e, then square it and log that number, you get 1.14.

Anyone able to point out what's going wrong here?

Comment: But what logarithm base do you need? log(1+e^2)=2.1269... is right because "log" by default uses base e. Which is mentioned in its documentation.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.log "With one argument, return the natural logarithm of x (to base e)."

Comment: No I used (1+math.exp(2)) for (1+e^2).
I did not realise it used base e and not base 10, thank you!

Comment: (Never mind, `e^2` is a type error, but please ensure your question reflects *exactly* what you are trying to do.)

Comment: Your question is lacking critical parts which leads to confusion. Check [\[SO\]: How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) or
[\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
for more asking related details. Add the *Python* code, and the sequence of keys you press on the calculator. It's obviously the base (or *lg* vs *ln*) in your case, but still

Answer (score 0):

Your calculator is using log to the base 10, while python's math library's `log` is log to the base e.

If you need log to the base 10 in python, use the `log10` function in the math library instead.

Answer (score 0):

`math.log` in Python is the natural logarithm (base `e`), sometimes called `ln`, especially on calculators. `log` on your calculator is the base 10 logarithm, which is `math.log10` in Python.